# Forward diode depletion capacitance formula

Tags: diodes, spice, modeling, ngspice, formula-derivation

Does anybody know the forward depletion capacitance formulas for diodes in spice models?

Background:
The capacitance of a diode in reverse direction usually is dominated by the depletion (or junction) capacitance \$C_J\$. The formula used in spice models is:

$$ C_J = C_{J0} (1-V_D/V_J)^{-M} $$

where \$V_D\$ is the voltage on the diode, \$V_J\$ is the work function and M is the grading coefficient, which describes the doping profile. This formula is good for reverse direction. In forward direction, it has the problem of a pole at \$V_D = V_J\$, predicting infinite capacitance.

Spice solves this by adding a parameter FC (default is 0.5) and use a different formula for \$V_D > V_J F_C\$. However, I could not find the information, which formula is used in this regime. Does somebody know, what this "forward bias depletion capacitance diode formula" looks like?

My best resource until now is the [ngspice manual](https://ngspice.sourceforge.io/docs/ngspice-manual.pdf), which gives these formulas:

$$ C_{depl_{bw}} = C_{J,eff}(1-V_D/V_J)^{-M_J} \text{, if } V_D < F_C V_J $$
$$ C_{depl_{bw}} = C_{J,eff}(1-F_C)^{-(1+M_J)}(1-F_C(1+M_J I) + M_J V_D/V_J) \text{, if } V_D \ge F_C V_J $$

However, there appears this \$I\$ and I have no clue what this I should be, or if this is just a typo.

Comment: A tangential comment here that might be interesting for you or someone else.  The formula for \$V_D \geq V_J \cdot F_C\$ is a linear extrapolation of the other formula.  So you can calculate the derivative of the main formula to get the slope at \$V_J \cdot F_C\$ and then solve using the generic equation for a line.  Don't worry if you're too lazy to do this.....I haven't done it myself either...

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just realized, that by inserting \$F_C V_J\$ into both formulas, this typo I must be 1 in order to be continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The \$I\$ looks to be a typo.  Instead of me copying the equations and introducing my own error, see the scan from [Semiconductor Device Modeling with SPICE (2nd ed.) by Massobrio & Antognetti](https://books.google.com/books?id=_QZTAAAAMAAJ) below:

[image]

Some terms are defined on previous pages so I'll give the jist of it.  \$C_D\$ is the total diode capacitance.  \$C_d\$ is the diffusion capacitance so ignore that term and just look at the \$C_j\$ part.  \$\phi_0\$ is the same as \$V_J\$ in your equations.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I notified ngspice about the typo.

Answer (score 2):

In **PSPICE (1987)** reference manual for diode:

\$C_j\$ is junction capacitance
\$Vd\$ is voltage across intrinsic diode only

For \$Vd\le FC\times VJ\$:
\$C_j=CJO\times (1-{Vd\over VJ})^{-M}\$

For \$Vd\gt FC\times VJ\$:
\$C_j=CJO \times (1-FC)^{-(1+M)}\times (1-FC(1+M)+M {Vd\over VJ})\$

A reference is given for this section in Chapter 6 of:
A.S.Grove, *Physics and Technology of Semiconductor Devices*, John Wiley and Sons, Inc., 1967